# Qt : Get the transport name from getmac

Tags: c++, qt

I am using **QNetworkInterface** class to get the mac id of the network interface. However, there is no option to get the transport name(GUID) of the network interface. Can somebody please help me with this. Please refer to the image and I need the highlighted portion from the image using Qt api. [image]

Comment: Which operating system? Maybe you need specific OS functions?

Comment: I need it for windows. Do you know any windows api which can give me this.

Answer (score 0):

After some google search i am able to get the transport name. Here is the code:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Iphlpapi.lib")

using namespace std;

int main() {
    PIP_INTERFACE_INFO pInfo = nullptr;
    ULONG ulOutBufLen = 0;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;

    if (GetInterfaceInfo(NULL, &ulOutBufLen)
        == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
        pInfo = (IP_INTERFACE_INFO *)malloc(ulOutBufLen);
    }

    dwRetVal = GetInterfaceInfo(pInfo, &ulOutBufLen);

    if (dwRetVal == NO_ERROR) {
        printf("Number of Adapters: %ld\n\n", pInfo->NumAdapters);

        for (auto i = 0; i<pInfo->NumAdapters; i++) {
            wcout<<"Adapter Name: " << pInfo->Adapter[i].Name << endl;
            printf("Adapter Index: %ld\n", pInfo->Adapter[i].Index);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("GetInterfaceInfo failed.\n");
        LPVOID lpMsgBuf;

        if (FormatMessage(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL,
            dwRetVal,
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL,
                SUBLANG_DEFAULT), /* Default language */
                (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
            0,
            NULL)) {
            printf("Error: %s", lpMsgBuf);
        }

        LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    }

    return 0;
}
```